# Passing objects with functions from PHP to JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've created a jQuery plugin that takes options in the form of an object. If I initialised the object client side I would do something like

```
$(selector).myPlugin({
    opt: value,
    id: 2,
    onclose: function () {},
});
```

My function would interpret the options as

```
1. {opt: string(value), id: int(2), onclose: function () {}}
```

However, the plugin declaration is made server side, and I turn a PHP associative array into the object required for the plugin options by using `json_encode`. The problem here is that my plugin recognises the declaration as

```
2. {opt: string(value), id: string(2), onclose: string(function () {})}
```

What I want to know is how do I pass that associative array from PHP in a way that JS interprets it as **1**

Comment: Parse and pass it as JSON, this way u can convert it back and forth in both languages

Comment: @darkbee That's the problem though, I get the object in **2**, which is incorrect. It interprets a function as a string

Comment: It shouldn't be encoding an integer as string from PHP.

Comment: @LukeMadhanga my bad, have to read full question next time '-_

Answer (score 0):

Cast your `id` value to an `int` before encoding the array to JSON:

```
$opts = array(
    'opt' => 'value',
    'id' => '2',
    'onclose' => 'function() {}'
);

$opts['id'] = (int)$opts['id'];

echo json_encode($opts);
```

Or even better would be if you cast the value for `id` before/during you construct the `$opts` array.